# Overheating causing applications to crash?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, games, overheating, kill

I am playing Cities Skylines on my Notebook. 
It's a Clevo W230ST. Specs:

- i7 4700MQ
- GTX 765M
- 8 Gig Ram
- Ubuntu 14.04.

I am using the Nvidia 331 Driver.

My questing is: Does some part of Ubuntu or the Nvidia driver actively kill applications that cause high load, when critical temperatures are reached? Because the system temps are indeed on the threshold of being critical, but yesterday it worked just fine. And the only thing that crashes is the game.

Answer (score 2):

Generally instead of stopping the application on overheating, the system will perform an emergency shut down, so I would say that heat is probably not the cause of this particular crash. The game wasn't released that long ago, so it isn't unreasonable for there to be a couple of problems that haven't been ironed out yet.

Evidence of Emergency Shutdown:

on the Arch subreddit [my_nvidia_gpu_is_overheating_can_someone_help_me](http://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/1yt2pu/my_nvidia_gpu_is_overheating_can_someone_help_me/)

on the CrunchBang Forum: [[Solved] Nvidia GPU overheating](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=27171)

Comment: +1 My old really Dell notebook which I rarely use now regularly does an emergency shutdown whenever the GPU gets too hot, in my case it is an ATI card but it should be the same for Nvidia cards also.

Comment: yep, in the mean time i was able to exclude overheating from the list of crash factors. Thanks for the Evidence ;)